# AnchorPane keeps growing despite having maxWidth property set

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am building simple GUI where the root element `StackPane` is having two children: `HBox` and `AnchorPane`.

[image: AnchorPane's width is growing]

Having set `maxWidth` property for all children components to `600`, `AnchorPane` still seems to grow horizontally when I only add any component to it and set this component's anchor to the value beyond `600`.

As you can see in above screenshot - `Label` in a bottom-right corner has left anchor set to `700` which leads to increase in `AnchorPane` width.

I would rather have this `Label` cut or placed beyond visible space.

Why is that? Can I somehow force `AnchorPane` to keep its maximal bounds? Is there any workaround for this issue?

You can find related java(fx) code [here](https://gist.github.com/MaciejDobrowolski/0111f8f1b9af590322db51e3f67325b6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why but, I tested it in SceneBuilder and changed some properties in fxml and it worked. I added `minWidth` to `StackPane` and `AnchorPane`.
This is my [fork](https://gist.github.com/mojtab23/2d4de6118d101db786496565b3427b4c).

Comment: You're right! The solution was to add `minWidth` property to `AnchorPane` child. It's little bit weird, but works! Thank you!

Comment: I have also submitted this bug - [JDK-8163075](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8163075)